# can you explain this limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ e^x}{x^n}=\infty$$ can anyone prove that.

Comment: Apply L'Hospitals rule $n$ times. Excuse me on the spelling.

Comment: Hint: consider the ratio $\frac {e^{x+1}}{(x+1)^n}\over\frac {e^x}{x^n}$...

Comment: this isnt prove this is accept and solve . I need the proof

Comment: Go tourdr and drop in your eye

Comment: This has been asked umpteen times before on this site...

Answer (score 2):

We can use the Taylor series for $e^x$:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x^n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Note that, for $k>n$ in the sum, the term is of an asymptotic order of $x^{k-n}$, which is greater than constant. Thus, the limit diverges to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $e^x = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i!} \geq 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \ldots+ \frac{x^n}{n!} + \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ for $x>0$. Thus, $\frac{e^x}{x^n} \geq \frac{1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \ldots+ \frac{x^n}{n!} + \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{x^n} = \frac{x}{(n+1)!} + $ some terms which go to zero. Taking limits of both sides shows the right hand side limit is infinity which means the left hand side limit is infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $e^x\ge \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ for all $n$.  Therefore, we have

$$\frac{e^x}{x^n}\ge \frac{x}{(n+1)!}\to \infty \,\,\text{as} \,\, x\to \infty$$